# Merging dict of dicts and sum values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I'm looking for a way to merge multiple dicts with each other, which contain nested dicts too. The number of nested dicts is not static but dynamic.

At the end the Final dict should contain all the dicts of dicts and the sum of their values:

```
COUNTRY1 = {'a': {'X': 10, 'Y': 18, 'Z': 17}, 'b': {'AA':{'AAx':45,'AAy':22},'BB':{'BBx':45,'BBy':22}}, 'c': 100}
COUNTRY2 = {'a': {'U': 12, 'V': 34, 'W': 23}, 'b': {'AA':{'AAz':23,'AAa':26},'BB':{'BBz':11,'BBa':15}}, 'c': 115}
COUNTRY3 = {'a': {'Y': 15, 'Z': 14, 'X': 12}, 'b': {'AA':{'AAx':45,'AAz':22},'BB':{'BBy':45,'BBz':22}}, 'c': 232}

# After merging the dictionaries the result should look like:
ALL
>>> {'a': {'X': 22, 'Y': 33, 'Z': 31, 'U': 12, 'V': 34, 'W': 23}, 'b': {'AA':{'AAx':90,'AAy':22,'AAz':45,'AAa':26},'BB':{'BBx':45,'BBy':67, 'BBz':33,'BBa':15}}, 'c': 447}
```

I tried the following code which allows nested dicts to a max of 3 nested dicts. Unfortunately the code doesn't do what I expected. Thereby it doesn't look very clean, I feel like this could be done with a recursive function, however I can't find a way to do it.

```
COUNTRIES = ['COUNTRY1','COUNTRY2', 'COUNTRY3']
ALL = {}
for COUNTRY_CODE in COUNTRIES:

    COUNTRY = pickle.load(open(COUNTRY_CODE+".p", "rb"))
    keys = COUNTRY.keys()
    for key in keys:
        try:
            keys2 = COUNTRY[key].keys()
            print(key, keys2)

            for key2 in keys2:
                try:
                    keys3 = COUNTRY[key][key2].keys()
                    print(key2, keys3)

                    for key3 in keys3:
                        try:
                            keys4 = COUNTRY[key][key2][key3].keys()
                            print(key3, keys4)
                        except:
                            print(key3, "NO KEY3")
                            if not key3 in ALL[key][key2]:
                                ALL[key][key2][key3] = COUNTRY[key][key2][key3]
                            else:
                                ALL[key][key2][key3] =+ COUNTRY[key][key2][key3]

                except:
                    print(key2, "NO KEY2")
                    if not key2 in ALL[key]:
                        ALL[key][key2] = COUNTRY[key][key2]
                    else:
                        ALL[key][key2] =+ COUNTRY[key][key2]

        except:
            print(key, "NO KEY")
            if not key in ALL:
                ALL[key] = COUNTRY[key]
            else:
                ALL[key] =+ COUNTRY[key]

print(ALL)
```

Comment: What you tried? Please paste something.

Comment: I just added my code to the post.

Comment: Where does your code fail? What does your current output look like?

Comment: The code seems to work if the keys in different dicts are unique however if the keys are the same, the second dictionary will overwrite the first dictionary's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two functions like below:

```
def cal_sum(lst):
    final_dict = dict()
    for l in lst:
        sum(final_dict,l)
    return final_dict

def sum(final_dict,iter_dict):
    for k, v in iter_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sum(final_dict.setdefault(k, dict()), v)
        elif isinstance(v, int):
            final_dict[k] = final_dict.get(k, 0) + v
```

Calling the above code as follows produces the desired output:

```
>>> print(cal_sum([COUNTRY1, COUNTRY2, COUNTRY3]))
{'a': {'U': 12, 'W': 23, 'V': 34, 'Y': 33, 'X': 22, 'Z': 31}, 'c': 447, 'b': {'AA': {'AAa': 26, 'AAy': 22, 'AAx': 90, 'AAz': 45}, 'BB': {'BBa': 15, 'BBz': 33, 'BBy': 67, 'BBx': 45}}}
```

Comment: Another clean looking answer however this didn't work for me in Python 3.6. I think iteritems() is not allowed on dicts anymore in Python 3?

Comment: @Sem Have updated the answer. Check if it works now?

Comment: For some reason some nested dicts are empty after running this code. I'll stick to the code of @Mad Physicist now, however thanks for the effort!

Comment: For the inputs in your question, it is working fine. Can you list the dicts for which it is causing the problem?

Comment: I found out it was because some values in my dicts were floats instead of ints. I changed the last elif to:
    elif isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float):
Which solved the problem. I like this solution as I can specify per type how to handle the data, this might be even more powerful than @Mad Physicist's solution.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you need to determine what to do with a dictionary key based on the type of the value. The basic idea is:

- Input is a pair of dictionaries, output is the sum dictionary
- Step along both input dictionaries
- If a value is a dictionary, recurse
- If a value is a number, add it to the other number

This is fairly easy to implement with a comprehension:

```
def add_dicts(d1, d2):
    def sum(v1, v2):
        if v2 is None:
            return v1
        try:
            return v1 + v2
        except TypeError:
            return add_dicts(v1, v2)
    result = d2.copy()
    result.update({k: sum(v, d2.get(k)) for k, v in d1.items()})
    return result
```

The copy ensures that any keys in `d2` that are not also in `d1` are simply copied over.

You can now sum as follows:

```
ALL = add_dicts(add_dicts(COUNTRY1, COUNTRY2), COUNTRY3)
```

More generally, you can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to do this for an indefinite number of dictionaries:

```
dicts = [COUNTRY1, COUNTRY2, COUNTRY3]
ALL = reduce(add_dicts, dicts)
```